# How does this Amazon Prime scam work?

Tags: united-kingdom, scams

It happened to me and to one relative: We both got a phone call that a payment of £79 for Amazon Prime would be taken from our credit card account. We both haven't subscribed to Amazon Prime, and both weren't keen to follow this up.

Clearly some kind of scam, but does anyone definitely know how this scam will continue? Convince you to hand over your credit card details so they can sort out the mistake?

Comment: FWIW I got the call too though I think it mentioned a bank account rather than a credit card. I hung up at the "press 1 to speak to someone" bit.

Comment: There are so many different variations of scams out there, I don't think it's possible to know exactly what any given setup is going to lead to without actually going along with it.

Comment: Amazon are making it easy to accidentally sign up for Prime. It is worth checking your Amazon account. Though don't think you'd get any phone call about it.

Comment: Now I work from home my UK landline can ring up to 4 times a day with these calls. Always a recorded female who sounds like an Indian lady who has learned English with an American accent. they always say AmaZON which sounds unnatural to a UK ear. Since I have no link with Amazon  or Amazon Prime whatsoever I know it's a scam. If I press 1 I get the typical Indian scam call centre spiel - they think I am called Mr XXXX where XXXX is the surname of the last person at this address. They are using computer auto dialling from an old UK phone number list. They want your bank details for a "refund".

Answer (score 6):

Usual drill on this form of scam is just to take you onto an official sounding automated process where you 'login' to your account to cancel it using the keypad/verbally etc, but where they just harvest your details and start spending.

Worth noting there are fairly basic heuristics you can always use to protect yourself from scams like this no matter how official they sound, such as always ringing off any cold calls and calling back your bank/cc provider via their official number etc.